# Angular ng-block-ui is not working in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, blockui

In my app.module.ts

```
import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BlockUIModule.forRoot(),
]
```

In my dashboard component

```
import { BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

@BlockUI() blockUI : NgBlockUI;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.blockUI.start()
 }

}
```

- Block Ui is not adding element in the Html
- i don't know what is the issue the block ui is not starting
- maybe the issue is related to angular version or not?
- **Angular version i am using is 7.**

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: no there is not any error in console

Comment: Can you show us your HTML template? Maybe you forgot to add the `<block-ui>` directive.

Comment: you should add it to your html too, made this stackblitz with angular 7.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-ng-block-ui

Answer (score 2):

**If ng-block-ui directive (*blockUI = "'your-variable'") isn't working in ANGULAR 7, 8 OR 9**

Then here is the solution.

First of all, if you followed [this](https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui) mentioned docs of ng-block-ui. And even it isn't working,

Then you need to install :

```
npm install ng-block-ui@next
```

this dependency in your angular project.

And if you are getting this error :

```
ng-block-ui: TypeError: Cannot read property 'localName' of null
at ng-block-ui.js:878
```

Then you need to install :

```
npm install ng-block-ui@next
```

[official bug link](https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui/issues/115)